# Rebooting twice after an update

Tags: windows, windows-update

When I first started learning about computers I was taught that after any updates I should always restart twice, but was never offered an explanation and I never thought to ask why.

Years on I still do this, mostly out of habit, and I still have no idea if it is beneficial.

The only thing I can think of is the OS gets a chance to configure itself then gets a fresh restart with all of the new settings.

Am I wasting my time here or does it have a positive effect?

Comment: Normally it shouldn't be necessary. The exeception would be when installing one set of updates means that more are then available and need to be installed.

Comment: You're wasting your time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting twice is not accomplishing much, if anything.

It can be beneficial to reboot *before* updating.  This would finalize any updates from the OS or applications that might prevent you from running an update.

After an update is applied, you might be required to reboot to apply those updates.  Once that update is complete, new updates might be available.  This typically happens when updates have to be applied in a certain order.  If new updates are available, they might require a reboot.  This is where I think your confusion is.  This situation happens often after installing an OS, or you havent updated the OS in a long time, and there are *many* updates that need to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Keltari's answer is pretty spot on. However, some of it depends on how the OS handles files currently loaded in memory.

Essentially, the reason that a restart is needed is because if a file that is loaded into memory gets updated, you need a way to get the new file into memory. For some files (mainly system files) it is necessary to restart the computer, however you only need to do this once.

From my understanding, Windows requires reboots for a lot more files because it's not as modular as Linux for example. Most updates in Linux would only require you to restart the specific service or program.